# Black screen after screen off on 13.10

Tags: 13.10, suspend, brightness, lock-screen

I swtiched "Turn screen off when inactive for" to 3 minutes and Lock screen after screen goes off to on. The problem is that after the screen is off, when I try to come back I can`t do anything, the screen keeps staying off and I need to restart. When I chose "Suspend" it's the same problem.